# JQuery Dynamic Dialog Div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

**Background:**
A table with rows is created dynamically with php on a page.
Using *jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js* and *jquery-1.5.1.min.js*
**Goal:**
I'd like to be able to click on a row which would update the Jquery Ui dialog div with new content from a php page and then display this content in the Jquery Ui dialog box.

```
$(function(){
  $('tr').live('click', function(){
    $('.ui-dialog').load('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/a/b/1');
    $('.ui-dialog').dialog('open');
  });
});
```

This code makes the dialog appear and disappear very fast without halting.
I've also tried the following which I thought would work:

```
$(function(){
  $('tr').live('click', function(){
    $('.ui-dialog').load('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/a/b/1',
      function(){
        $('.ui-dialog').dialog('open')
    });
  });
});
```

Dialog code:

```
$(function(){$('.ui-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        open: function(){
                        $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeIn();},
        beforeClose: function(){
                        $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeOut();},
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade", 
        buttons: {
        "Back to search": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    })});
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what state is the `".ui-dialog"` ... hidden I assume? Can you check that the `load()` is returning the correct html? and is successful? for example `.load('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/a/b/1',function(responseText){ alert(responseText); ...`

Comment: The '".ui-dialog"' is set to display:none. I can get it to display properly without trying to change the content of the dialog div.
'load()' is returning the correct HTML and is successful with your example code.

Comment: Are you adding any open dialog event handlers? have you tried adding some static hardcoded content and then try opening the dialog?

Comment: Hard coded static content works.
eg:`$(function(){$('tr').live('click', function(){$('.ui-dialog').dialog('open')})});`

Open dialog event handlers? As in the .dialog('close') etc?

Comment: events as in http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open it looks like from your edit you are `open: function{ ..` but it looks safe. try putting a `return false;` in your click event maybe it is bubbling and causing something else to run? I would still suggest it is your ajax call returning bad html or writing over something.

Comment: Ignore that last comment i just worked it out -.- look at the answer i added.

Comment: `return false` doesn't solve it. I'll recheck the calls again. thanks for your help.

Comment: Ignore that return false; Its because you're initialiseing the dialog then deleting all the added html it put. Checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you initialise like :

```
$(function(){$('.ui-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    open: function(){
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeIn();},
    beforeClose: function(){
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeOut();},
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade", 
    buttons: {
    "Back to search": function() { 
        $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
})});
```

It adds HTML to the `.ui-dialog` when you `.load()` it removes it.

What you need to do is either put the initialise code **after** the ajax load or:

```
$(function(){
  $('tr').live('click', function(){
    $('.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content').load('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/a/b/1',
      function(){
        $('.ui-dialog').dialog('open')
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hgeYs/4/

Comment: Excellent thanks very much. Basically just the ui-dialog-content i left out thinking the ui-dialog was the selector. Can't believe I didn't come across that online! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').live('click', function() {
        var obj = $('<div/>');
        obj.load('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/a/b/1', function() {
            obj.dialog({
                close: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog("destroy")
                }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: $(this) is referring to the 'tr' and changing that fine BUT what I'm trying to do is change what will appear in the dialog box when it appears.

Comment: then load to standalone element and dialog it, don't forget to destroy dialog, after close,
I will edit to show sample

Comment: Perfect.thanks. One thing just so I can be enlightened: Why does it work when it is loaded to a standalone element?

Comment: what you mean ? `$('<div/>')` creates brand new div, i also think that '.ui-dialog' is mess things, because looks like jqueryui class,

Comment: Is my 2nd example not doing the same thing as this code? I'm using JqueryUI.

Comment: why need to have ui-dialog class if you need just empty element, my sample creates brand new element.

Comment: So is it essential that I create a new instance every time?
Ref: http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/